# What is the Sephardi, Mizrahi and Teimoni equivalent of a nigun?

Tags: music

A nigun is classically understood to be a, usually, vocal-less hymn that early Hassidim in Europe invented. Is this phenomenon found in Jewish communities other than (Eastern European dynasty) Ashkenazi Hassidic circles?

My reasoning for this is that music is a cultural by product of all civilizations (and their faiths).

Comment: "classically" "early Hassidim": Do you mean, like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chassidei_Ashkenaz ?

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect those other communities would have a parallel concept if it isn't based in Jewish tradition?

Comment: I don't understand. The word nigun is Hebrew (vayinagen haminagen), not some Yiddish invention. So the word for tune in those other cultures would be ... Nigun.

Comment: Perhaps Pizmon?

Comment: The last sentence indicates that this question is about music as a universal "cultural by-product," which doesn't seem on-topic. If the question is specifically about tunes used for certain religious purposes, please [edit] to make that clear. Also, are you asking whether tunes fulfilling such functions exist, for more detail about those functions, simply for the word used to denote such tunes, or something else? Please [edit] to clarify that, too.